# Where can I find food-grade beeswax to make Canelé?

Tags: pastry

I am looking for food-grade beeswax to make Canelé.  On Amazon, all I can seem to find is "cosmetic grade" which is not necessarily meant for food usage.

Comment: Does it have to be beeswax specifically? I know it has a higher melting point than some waxes but it's surely going to melt either way.

Comment: It doesn't actually all melt away, beeswax are used to coat the tins you cook canele in and there is a thin layer of beeswax left on the cakes as you eat them.  It has to be an edible wax and beeswax is traditional.

Comment: I didn't say it melted away, just that it would fully melt (before ultimately resolidifying). Beeswax melts around 145F (63C), and given that we're talking about baked goods I assume it's going to be way over that temperature, and the exact melting point of the wax would seem to not be critical. So any other food-grade wax would be a potential substitute even if not as traditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Adisak I was able to find one  [source](http://www.marshallshoney.com/p-15-beeswax-food-grade-by-the-pound.aspx) , although there may be many more.

I also found food grade paraffin wax, but it seems that it has a much lower melting point.

After a little reading it seems that making canelés can be a quite tricky and meticulous process, so you probably want to stick with the beeswax. They do sound delicious!

Answer (score 3):

Try finding a small regional beekeeper, or a beekeeper selling over the Internet. Especially one of those who produce high-quality organic honey. He will probably have a range of other bee products. Even if he doesn't list or display wax for sale, he might have some, just ask.

I've mostly seen this type of beekeeper present at farmer's markets and similar places, but they are probably not so hard to find on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rumtscho that a beekeeper would be the best place to go. In the event that you don't know any beekeepers, try the bulk section at a health food store or coop. They frequently have either small blocks or pellets that are sold by weight.